# Spring mvc resources not applying

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, resources, datatables

Helo, I have strange problem with my web application.
Something wrong is going on with resources.
When I start my project on server css files loads and apply styles on jsp but as soon as I refresh the page all styles disappear and I'm getting those warnings:

```
sie 24, 2015 2:09:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported
sie 24, 2015 2:09:56 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver logException
WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Here is my dispatcher:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fileValidator"
    class="com.seemlyMike.Util.FileValidator" />

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="validation" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.seemlyMike" />
<mvc:resources cache-period="31556926" location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<display-name>ImportExcel</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Tables</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="resources/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Custom Scripts -->
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
    <script>if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

        alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

    }else{

        alert("jQuery library is not found!");

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
package com.seemlyMike.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TableController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/table" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

        model.setViewName("table");

        return model;

    }

}
```

All resources are:

```
webapp/resources/
```

Comment: Is there any resource restriction on your resource files? Do you have Spring security enabled in this project?

Comment: Nop, I'm not using Spring Security. I've used Spring security in other project and everything was working. In this project I haven't even add Spring security dependencies.

Comment: @seemlyMike my resources are placed within webapp/WEB-INF/resources, can you try placing them inside /WEB-INF ? would also need to then change to location="/WEB-INF/resources/" in your dispatcher.xml

Comment: @smoggers Done, didnt work, same warnings :(

Comment: @seemlyMike ok I have another idea, in my jsp I have within my <head> tags a different way of locating resources, like this: <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> can you try this way ?

Comment: @smoggers Tried that earlier, that also doesn't work.

Comment: @seemlyMike fair enough I've upvoted your question so hopefully somebody will be able to pinpoint the issue

Comment: Any warning/error in the browser console during refresh?

Comment: @GergelyBacso Only those I've mentioned.

Comment: I think those logs are not from your browser console. Check this out: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console .

Answer (score 0):

you can try following way add like this in all css and js:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```